How to Display Data in Observable Hexbin
I am experimenting with my own data in the Hexbin map (from the plot gallery). Here is the link: https://observablehq.com/d/010a05ef3db6634b
I've connected it to my vehicles tsv file. I want to now plot the hexbins. Not sure what I'm missing...
I am expecting bins to show on the map based on Electric(EV) values. So, larger values would be larger bins.

The Observable tag doesn't mean what you think it does. Surely this question would be better for their internal support? https://talk.observablehq.com/

@OneCricketeer Hey there, thanks for your help! I posted on their forum...didn't realize it existed!
